# Notification activity crashing

Tags: android, crash, notificationmanager

```
package com.example.khatrimann.notification;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    b.setTicker("khatrimann")
            .setContentTitle("Default notification")
            .setContentText("Hey There.")
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());
}
}
```

This code is tested on marshmallow, it is crashing and is not working.

android.support.v4 and v7, both are tried one by one then also the app crashes.

LOGCAT IS AS FOLLOWS:

```
11-20 18:24:59.623 4146-4146/com.example.khatrimann.notification E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.khatrimann.notification, PID: 4146
                                                                               Theme: themes:{default=overlay:system, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:system, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.khatrimann.notification/com.example.khatrimann.notification.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.example.khatrimann.notification/0x1090085 vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.example.khatrimann.notification/0x1090085 vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
                                                                                   at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:223)
                                                                                   at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:195)
                                                                                   at com.example.khatrimann.notification.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The Error is shown is FATAL of main

Comment: post the logcat here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a notification you must add a small icon, like this code example.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
   new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
   .setContentTitle("My notification")
   .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

Comment: yeah!! tried on the studio, it worked. By mistakenly in the documentation, I skipped this part. PS: Unable to up-vote as I do not have enough reps.